# How do I connect to FreeNAS share on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, freenas

I was wondering if someone can help me connect to my FreeNAS shares from my main PC running Windows 10. I just can't figure out how to mount the shares so that I can access the drives in the NAS. It's really confusing.

Comment: Make sure time is sync on freenas from a reliable ntp server, then at command prompt run the following command and report the error: net use \\nasiporname /user:usernamewithsmbperm myStr0ngP@ssw9rd. Instead of password in clear text you may also use a single star * to be asked

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is perhaps that from Windows 10 version 1709, guest access in SMB2
has been disabled by default.

To enable:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Lanman Workstation*
- Double-click "Enable Insecure guest logons"
- Click Enabled
- Click OK

This setting somewhat reduces the security of Windows.
If this worries you, you will need to change on the FreeNAS side the SAMBA
settings to prompt for a username/password.

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work for me. I just did a fresh install of FreeNAS. I have the NAS connected directly to my PC using an Ethernet cable.

Comment: If everything is set up correctly then the shares should be visible in Explorer/Network. Please add the SAMBA config file to the post (smb.conf).